# How can I pass a parameter to an authorization handler used in a policy, through a controller

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, policy

I've been searching for an answer to this, but I can't seem to find a straight answer. I have an Authorization Handler that is used in a Policy. The typical example is below:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    });
```

And then the policy is specified in the authorization attribute on the controller. What I want to do is specify the age requirement at the controller level. For Example:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21", 21)]
```

The idea would be that I could use the same Authorization Handler for multiple controller actions, or multiple policies.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize **authorization attributes and authorization policy providers** to meet your needs.

You can **[click on this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2177224.aspx)** to view a detailed example I wrote earlier.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have read about those, but I was really hoping there was a simple way to do it with the Authorization Handler only. It almost seems like at this point it would be easier to do the same job with a custom action filter.